# How to find the type of the caller of a function in Rust?

Tags: function, reflection, rust

How can I get the caller type in my function?

```
struct A;
struct B;

impl A {
    fn new() -> Self {
        A
    }
    fn call_function(&self) {
        B::my_function();
    }
}

impl B {
    pub fn my_function() {
        println!("Hello");
        // println!("{}" type_of_the_caller) // I want to get type A here
        // Is it possible to get the caller type which is A in this case?
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A::new();
    a.call_function();
}
```

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d8b475aeb50493f092235713a22c286d&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) is the working code in playground. This is simplified code for an example.

Comment: I guess you meant `fn call_function(&self)`? Please add more precision about what you want to do with the type of the caller

Comment: @Boiethios clarified the question

Comment: You didn't understand my question: why do you want the type of the caller? Rust is not a dynamic language nor has reflection so it isn't possible as is. I suspect that you're doing some kind of cargo cult.

Comment: I see, I was trying to implement publish subscribe design and did not wanted to explicitly specify the subscriber type, since the subscriber calls the subscribe method itself. So I guess, I need to pass it's reference or at least it's type explicity for subscription?

Comment: Ok. In this case, you need to use a trait `Suscriber` (for example) with the desired methods in it, and each suscriber **must** implement this trait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust doesn't have any machinery like this built-in. If you want to know some context inside a function then you'll need to pass it in as an argument.

Also, Rust doesn't have a way to get the name of a type, so you'd have to provide that too. For example, with a trait:

```
trait Named {
    fn name() -> &'static str;
}

impl Named for A {
    fn name() -> &'static str {
        "A"
    }
}
```

Which you might use like this:

```
impl B {
    pub fn my_function<T: Named>(_: &T) {
        println!("Hello");
        println!("{}", T::name());
    }
}
```

You just have to pass in the caller when you call it:

```
impl A {
    fn call_function(&self) {
        B::my_function(self);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Hello
A
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have the compiler write the boilerplate by creating a macro and making use of the `stringify!` macro.

```
struct A;
struct B;
struct C;

trait Named {
    fn name() -> &'static str;
}

macro_rules! make_named {
    ( $($x:ty),* ) => {
        $(
        impl Named for $x {
            fn name() -> &'static str {
                stringify!($x)
            }
        }
        )*
    };
}

make_named!(A, B);
make_named!(C);

fn main() {
    println!("{:#?}", A::name());
    println!("{:#?}", B::name());
    println!("{:#?}", C::name());
}
```

[playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=d045a01000df55d9081da1a938249581&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)